# Strapi override admin panel controller

Tags: strapi

I am interested in overriding the strapi admin panel webhook controller to give it some more functionality. e.g. Allowing customization on a per model level instead of every entity create/update/delete calling the webhook. It seems like you cant override controllers by just adding them to the admin folder like you can other parts of the admin frontend. Im looking for advice on how to proceed with this or if creating a custom plugin is my only option at this point.

Thanks, Jordy

Comment: can you give an example (or 2) of what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

if you want to customize the admin panel, you will have to follow this documentation - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html

It's the same for the admin part of a plugin.

Comment: This should probably be a comment. An answer telling people to go read the documentation is not a very good answer.